# how to automate a backtesting strategy in pine?

Tags: pine-script

Is there a way to compare the best value of a backtest strategy in pine?
So it should automatically backtest all (in this case) 3000 possibilities and choose the one with the highest value amount?

Answer (score 0):

At the moment, there are no such tools for optimizing strategies in Pine.